# Any way to see all the transcripts of Expert chat?

Tags: support, april-fools

It would be of interest at least to those working on Eliza-like software.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Nope, it's intentional that the session ids are random strings instead of guessable numbers. If someone wants to share a transcript that's fine, but some of the contents of those conversations are probably better left under the rug, in particular where the user didn't realize they were talking to a bot and/or they posted private, confidential, identifying etc. information.

As an example (leaving out the obviously good amount of verbal abuse that the bot gets), he/she/it has actually been offered money to finish an iOS developer's project (and this included an email address being posted).

Comment: **offered money to finish an iOS developer's project** ...hahahahahha ROFL

Comment: Oh my goodness gracious, please tell me you guys are going to assemble a best-of...

Comment: omg you are right http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/174532/176320

Comment: @Charles I had some free time this morning waiting for a report to run, so I felt like trolling the bot with requests for weaponizing ponies and catching unicorns with waffles... given some of the responses, I think a "Best Of" (carefully redacted) would be fantastic

Comment: @Charles At this moment we have over 34000 chat sessions where the user has at least posted one message. Who's going to read all of that? :)

Comment: @balpha A bot, of course.

Comment: @balpha What's got two thumbs and would read that? This guy.

Comment: @balpha, I smell the need for a new review queue!